# How can I unpublish the content profile node when users update their user account?

Tags: 6, rules, users

I would like to unpublish automatically the content profile node of the users who updates their user account at user/%/eidt.

I found a event "User account details have been updated" in Rules but didn't find the action to unpublish their content profile node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also a hook you can use to react to user operations. Could do something pretty simple like this (untested code btw, you'll also have to adapt it for the name of your content type):

```
<?php
  /**
   * Implements hook_user()
   */
  function MODULENAME_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    if( $op == 'update' ) {
      $type = 'name_of_your_profile_content_type';
      $profile = content_profile_load($type, $account->uid);
      $profile->status = 0;
      node_save($profile);
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Set data"-action to set the profile node's status to 0: `status=1` means published, `status=0` means unpublished.

Comment: Where is "Set data"-action ? I can't find it..